# Where or how to configure Service Timeouts?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, timeout

I have a WCF service and an application.

My application calls the wcf service like so:

```
string endpointAddress = "https:\\mywebsite.com\myservice\service.svc;
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 524288000;
binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);

EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress(address);
ChannelFactory<T> client = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, endPointAddress);
IClientChannel proxy = (IClientChannel)client.CreateChannel();
```

and the web.config file for my service reads:

```
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Secure" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="10485760" maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760" maxBytesPerRead="10485760" maxNameTableCharCount="10485760" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
```

but my service call times out after 30 seconds.
Why does my service call not use the Web.config timeout? What is the reason for having web.config settings if client settings are always used? and which Timeout property do I need to set to stop my service call timing out after 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using This Link I found that:](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d/explaination-of-different-timeout-types?forum=wcf)

**Client side:**

SendTimeout is used to initialize the OperationTimeout, which governs the whole interaction for sending a message (including receiving a reply message in a request-reply case).  This timeout also applies when sending reply messages from a CallbackContract method.

OpenTimeout and CloseTimeout are used when opening and closing channels (when no explicit timeout value is passed).

ReceiveTimeout is not used.

**Server side:**

Send, Open, and Close Timeout same as on client (for Callbacks).

ReceiveTimeout is used by ServiceFramework layer to initialize the session-idle timeout.

So in this case I set my SendTimeout property to be 2 minutes. Although this doesn't explain my 30 second timeout. I have a feeling this may be to do with a database connection timeout